# How to change the Cordova splash screen and resize it

Tags: cordova, mobile, screen, splash-screen

I created an android app with Cordova. Which we t smoothly until the splash, I finally.was able to change the splash screen(change only the logo) but it does not show properly ,like it cuts out my image a little, so just thought the image was too big and decided to reduce them but to no avail

I tried reducing the images but it did not work

Thus is an image of my config.xml file where I made some changes for the splash screen

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhKNb.png

This is how the splash screen shows

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4EzZK.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your image but, if it has a transparent background, you need to set the proper border (empty space around your logo). Changing the size of the image will not change how it appears.

Check out [this page](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/launch/splash-screen#:%7E:text=Splash%20screen%20dimensions,-The%20splash%20screen&text=Branded%20image%3A%20this%20must%20be,circle%20192%20dp%20in%20diameter.)

> App icon with an icon background: this must be 240×240 dp and fit within a circle 160 dp in diameter.

> App icon without an icon background: this must be 288×288 dp and fit within a circle 192 dp in diameter.

Comment: I just edited the images, please do check it out